# How to send a mail using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem by specifying the From Address

Tags: c#, email, outlook, vsto

I'm using Interop for sending e-mails via Outlook, but I am not able to specify the From e-mail address.

I want to send mails to multiple users originating from the same sender (from). I need to mention the from e-mail address. However I cannot find a property using Intellisense that allows me to specify it.

Please help.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application olkApp1 = 
    new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem olkMail1 =
    (MailItem)olkApp1.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
        olkMail1.To = txtpsnum.Text;
        olkMail1.CC = "";
        olkMail1.Subject = "Assignment note";
        olkMail1.Body = "Assignment note";
        olkMail1.Attachments.Add(AssignNoteFilePath, 
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, 1, 
                "Assignment_note");
olkMail1.Save();
//olkMail.Send();
```

Answer (score 14):

You are using outlook to send the mail. Since outlook must be configured to use the `from` address of your mail, you cannot provide the `from` address directly. However, you can select an account available on outlook. For example :

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

Outlook.Accounts accounts = olkApp1.Session.Accounts;
foreach (Outlook.Account account in accounts)
{
    // When the e-mail address matches, send the mail.
    if (account.SmtpAddress == "from@mail.com")
    {
            olkMail1.SendUsingAccount = account;
            ((Outlook._MailItem)olkMail1).Send();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for including the using portion of this. Took me forever to find that. I'm not sure how developers normally know what 'using' stuff they need to include?

Comment: @Eric You can code the using {} block for any class that implements IDisposable. When the using block ends, the variable defined in it is automatically disposed.

Comment: @j2associates I think they meant the namespace/alias "using"

Answer (score 7):

The [Send](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.send.aspx) method sends the mail using the default account. To specify a different account to send the mail, set the [SendUsingAccount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.sendusingaccount.aspx) property to the desired [Account](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.account.aspx) prior to calling the Send method.

```
var application = new Application();
var mail = (_MailItem) application.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
mail.To = "anonymous@somedomain.com";
....
Outlook.Account account = Application.Session.Accounts["MyOtherAccount"];
mailItem.SendUsingAccount = account;
mail.Send();
```

More information can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff184652.aspx

Comment: How can I create my mail, and open it? (like a mailto?). Save put the mail in non send mail, but can we have a window with the new create mail?

Comment: @Zaphod: use `mail.Display(false)` to display email as a non-modal window.

Comment: @RomanD.Boiko :thanks for your comment, that's what i was searching for.

Comment: I tried to do this, it worked for me, but when it sends the email, instead of the sender being the one I specified, it sends it with the default one. Why does this happen? How can I fix it?