# C# MailMessage Display email instead of Send

Tags: c#, .net, mailmessage

I have been following the example below to send email using C# code with success:
[MSDN Mail Message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage(v=vs.110).aspx)

However, I would like the code to display the composed email message on user machine, so that user can have a final check before hitting send button on outlook.

In the VBA world, I can use mail.Display in place of mail.Send.
Can anyone provide some advice to achieve that in C#?

Thanks.

Comment: The sample you are using has nothing to do with Outlook, can work with any mail server

Comment: Is this for a desktop application, or ASP.NET?

Comment: This is for Desktop Application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a great solution to my problem i.e. to use Microsoft Office Interop Outlook instead of System.Net.MailMessage

followed this:
[How to send a mail using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem by specifying the From Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223462/how-to-send-a-mail-using-microsoft-office-interop-outlook-mailitem-by-specifying)

```
//using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook; 

    public static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            SendUsingAccountExample();
        }


        private static void SendUsingAccountExample()
        {
            var application = new Application();
            var mail = (_MailItem)application.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
            mail.Body = "Hello";
            mail.Subject = "Good Bye";
            mail.To = "hello@google.com";
            // Next 2 lines are optional. if not specified, the default account will be used
            Outlook.Account account = Application.Session.Accounts["MyOtherAccount"];
            mail.SendUsingAccount = account;


            mail.Display(false); // To Display
            //mail.Send(); // To Send

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this...

```
private void btnEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{ 
   string command = "mailto:somebody@domain.com?subject=The Subject&bcc=another@codegaim.com&body=Hi,I found this website and thought you might like it http://www.geocities.com/wowhtml/";  
   Process.Start(command); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mick, my email message is in HTML form. How do I use this?

Comment: You would have to encode the html... could get tricky, but HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode might do it for you...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w(v=vs.110).aspx