# c# Send Email using Process.Start

Tags: c#, email, outlook

I want to send simple email with no attachment using default email application.

I know it can be done using Process.Start, but I cannot get it to work. Here is what I have so far:

```
string mailto = string.Format("mailto:{0}?Subject={1}&Body={2}", "to@user.com", "Subject of message", "This is a body of a message");
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(mailto);
```

But it simply opens Outlook message with pre-written text. I want to directly send this without having user to manually click "Send" button. What am I missing?

Thank you

Comment: Why are expecting that to be like that? I'm glad no random application can send email using my email program without me knowing or seeing anything.

Comment: use the `SmtpClient` class.

Comment: If problem occurs within the application, I want to automatically send error log to system administrator.

Comment: Automating Outlook via COM Interop is the best way if for whatever reason you *must* use Outlook. For the command line see; [Sending email from Command-line via outlook without having to click send](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433202/sending-email-from-command-line-via-outlook-without-having-to-click-send). For a general solution for other e-mail clients, your out of luck - there is no such common interface.

Comment: The process start will not fully automate the sending of the email. It will only open it ready to send (as you have seen)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending email from Command-line via outlook without having to click send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433202/sending-email-from-command-line-via-outlook-without-having-to-click-send)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do this:

```cs
SmtpClient m_objSmtpServer = new SmtpClient();
MailMessage objMail = new MailMessage();
m_objSmtpServer.Host = "YOURHOSTNAME";
m_objSmtpServer.Port = YOUR PORT NOS;

objMail.From = new MailAddress(fromaddress);
objMail.To.Add("TOADDRESS");

objMail.Subject = subject;
objMail.Body = description;
m_objSmtpServer.Send(objMail);
```

Comment: Yes I have seen this solution, but I want to achieve this using Process.Start

Comment: I believe that using Process.Start you will not be able to do it .It will simply open the Outlook.

Answer (score 5):

You need to do this :

```
string mailto = string.Format("mailto:{0}?Subject={1}&Body={2}", "to@user.com", "Subject of message", "This is a body of a message");
mailto = Uri.EscapeUriString(mailto);
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(mailto);
```

Comment: How is this different from what OP is already doing? This will not send the message automatically. It will simply be shown on the screen.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about `Process.Start()` this will probably always only open a mail message in the default Mail-App and not send it automatically.

But there may be two alternatives:

- Send directly via [SmtpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201239/send-e-mail-via-smtp-using-c-sharp) Class
- using [Outlook.Interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223462/how-to-send-a-mail-using-microsoft-office-interop-outlook-mailitem-by-specifying)