# How send email with an email window already opened, using Outlook Interop in c#?

Tags: c#, email, selenium, outlook, office-interop

I'm working with a script that does a password reset function in a section of a page, when the user click the "Reset" button in the webpage it executes the "mailto" and appear a "new email" window of outlook,

how can I send a mail that includes some information of the webpage (like temporary password) in the body of the mail message and then send it?

The script I'm developing is with Selenium.

Comment: you can do this with a simple google search there are tons of examples use this as a starting base http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26403861/c-sharp-send-email-using-process-start

Comment: I don't want to create an new email object (window), I want to use the one that is already opened. The current Item, but don't worry I already found the answer https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/8639b051-2b96-4210-bc80-f87fdc0b8c76/how-to-access-the-outlook-email-compose-message-body?forum=winforms

Comment: Does your mailto link include the "body" parameter?

Answer (score 0):

The "mailto" command doesn't make any sense if you need to send the auto-generated email programmatically. Instead, I'd suggest developing any web-service for sending emails programmatically, so you can call it from a script without disturbing users.

Moreover, you can't be sure that all users have set the default email client to Outlook.